# How to present a lot of choices and options, where each case is important?

Tags: text, placement, options, choices, many-options

[image]
Can't show app interface but here is the concept. 1st image situation and a short description of the person. The Second image is Cases and options for how to help. (First, you choose case then option).

The problem is

1. Placing a large amount of text. I can't shorten the text, but in case 3 and options this requires a reduction in font and line break. How to organize it without cutting a text and with normal appearance
2. How to organize all cases for choice?

I guess it will be difficult for the user to read each case and choose. And a sense of congestion of the interface

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "How to organize all cases for choice?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would approach this problem:

1. **Layout:** Browsing a grid (1) is much harder than a list, perhaps you can break it up.
2. **Grouping**: Information is much easier to understand when grouped
   logically. I don't know your content, but you can probably form
   groups. Then color code them, frame them, etc., make it subtle but obvious.
3. **Text**: centred text is hard to scan. look at this page, everything is aligned to the left. Reserve centred text for the one important button
4. **Flow**: Area 2 is a result of the selection of area 1? If yes, this should be made obvious visually.

As for your **case 3** problem: Does it need to be a button/pill? Could it also be a header? Or a tab? Then the text line could break.

Here is an example I found not too far away:

[image: screenshot from stackexchange]

Just like in your example: left selection, right: resulting list

**Generally**, the purpose of the screen needs to be clear. What is the user supposed to do? This workflow needs to be supported by the UI, not the other way around.

Comment: every case needs to be a button. like it's illness name and after pressing it would appear options to heal it.
Users need to choose a situation and what to do in these situations.
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: That doesn't mean it has to be a button. e.g. not everything on this page is a button, yet you managed to navigate it.

Comment: I amended my answer